# Faced with error: nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when run java application as service in CentOs

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, service, centos

I have a spring-boot web application and today I deploy it to Linux system. My application uses HSM device so it use a library called `jcryptoki` to work with it.
My service is deployed and run well, but unfortunately, I am facing with below error when executing business function:
`nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jcryptoki in java.library.path`

[here](https://medium.com/@ameyadhamnaskar/running-java-application-as-a-service-on-centos-599609d0c641) is the document that I referred to create a service.

When I run this app as normal by run command `java -jar ...` it's worked well.

I found the same error occur when missing the lib path declaration $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Maybe when running application as a service, the system cannot be found this lib path.

I run both case as root account, have I lost anything in configuration or permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem caused by the missing Environment declaration variable on the service definition file.
With specific declaration variable: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/safenet/protecttoolkit5/cpsdk/lib/linux-x86_64/` I add new file named imported_inv (located in etc/default) with content as above. In the service defination file, I declare additional info like this
[image]

reload service and then it works like a charm.